# Converting a set to a list with Pandas grouopby agg function causes 'ValueError: Function does not reduce'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Sometimes, it seems that the more I use Python (and Pandas), the less I understand. So I apologise if I'm just not seeing the wood for the trees here but I've been going round in circles and just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Basically, I have an example script (that I'd like to implement on a much larger dataframe) but I can't get it to work to my satisfaction.

The dataframe consists of columns of various datatypes. I'd like to group the dataframe on 2 columns and then produce a new dataframe that contains lists of all the unique values for each variable in each group. (Ultimately, I'd like to concatenate the list items into a single string – but that's a different question.)

The initial script I used was:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def tempFuncAgg(tempVar):
    tempList = set(tempVar.dropna()) # Drop NaNs and create set of unique values
    print(tempList)
    return tempList

# Define dataframe
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                        'date': ["02/04/2015 02:34","06/04/2015 12:34","09/04/2015 23:03","12/04/2015 01:00","15/04/2015 07:12","21/04/2015 12:59","29/04/2015 17:33","04/05/2015 10:44","06/05/2015 11:12","10/05/2015 08:52","12/05/2015 14:19","19/05/2015 19:22","27/05/2015 22:31","01/06/2015 11:09","04/06/2015 12:57","10/06/2015 04:00","15/06/2015 03:23","19/06/2015 05:37","23/06/2015 13:41","27/06/2015 15:43"],
                        'gender': ["male","female","female","male","male","female","female",np.nan,"male","male","female","male","female","female","male","female","male","female",np.nan,"male"],
                        'age': ["young","old","old","old","old","old",np.nan,"old","old","young","young","old","young","young","old",np.nan,"old","young",np.nan,np.nan]})

# Groupby based on 2 categorical variables
tempGroupby = tempDF.groupby(['gender','age'])

# Aggregate for each variable in each group using function defined above
dfAgg = tempGroupby.agg(lambda x: tempFuncAgg(x))
print(dfAgg)
```

The output from this script is as expected: a series of lines containing the sets of values and a dataframe containing the returned sets:

```
{'09/04/2015 23:03', '21/04/2015 12:59', '06/04/2015 12:34'}
{'01/06/2015 11:09', '12/05/2015 14:19', '27/05/2015 22:31', '19/06/2015 05:37'}
{'15/04/2015 07:12', '19/05/2015 19:22', '06/05/2015 11:12', '04/06/2015 12:57', '15/06/2015 03:23', '12/04/2015 01:00'}
{'02/04/2015 02:34', '10/05/2015 08:52'}
{2, 3, 6}
{18, 11, 13, 14}
{4, 5, 9, 12, 15, 17}
{1, 10}
                                                           date  \
gender age                                                        
female old    set([09/04/2015 23:03, 21/04/2015 12:59, 06/04...   
       young  set([01/06/2015 11:09, 12/05/2015 14:19, 27/05...   
male   old    set([15/04/2015 07:12, 19/05/2015 19:22, 06/05...   
       young          set([02/04/2015 02:34, 10/05/2015 08:52])   

                                      id  
gender age                                
female old                set([2, 3, 6])  
       young       set([18, 11, 13, 14])  
male   old    set([4, 5, 9, 12, 15, 17])  
       young                set([1, 10])
```

The problem occurs when I try to convert the sets to lists. Bizarrely, it produces 2 duplicated rows containing identical lists but then fails with a 'ValueError: Function does not reduce' error.

```
def tempFuncAgg(tempVar):
    tempList = list(set(tempVar.dropna()))   # This is the only difference
    print(tempList)
    return tempList


tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                        'date': ["02/04/2015 02:34","06/04/2015 12:34","09/04/2015 23:03","12/04/2015 01:00","15/04/2015 07:12","21/04/2015 12:59","29/04/2015 17:33","04/05/2015 10:44","06/05/2015 11:12","10/05/2015 08:52","12/05/2015 14:19","19/05/2015 19:22","27/05/2015 22:31","01/06/2015 11:09","04/06/2015 12:57","10/06/2015 04:00","15/06/2015 03:23","19/06/2015 05:37","23/06/2015 13:41","27/06/2015 15:43"],
                        'gender': ["male","female","female","male","male","female","female",np.nan,"male","male","female","male","female","female","male","female","male","female",np.nan,"male"],
                        'age': ["young","old","old","old","old","old",np.nan,"old","old","young","young","old","young","young","old",np.nan,"old","young",np.nan,np.nan]})

tempGroupby = tempDF.groupby(['gender','age'])

dfAgg = tempGroupby.agg(lambda x: tempFuncAgg(x))
print(dfAgg)
```

But now the output is:

```
['09/04/2015 23:03', '21/04/2015 12:59', '06/04/2015 12:34']
['09/04/2015 23:03', '21/04/2015 12:59', '06/04/2015 12:34']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ValueError: Function does not reduce
```

Any help to troubleshoot this problem would be appreciated and I apologise in advance if it's something obvious that I'm just not seeing.

EDIT
Incidentally, converting the set to a tuple rather than a list works with no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists can sometimes have weird problems in pandas. You can either :

1. Use tuples (as you've already noticed)
2. If you really need lists, just do it in a second operation like this :

   `dfAgg.applymap(lambda x: list(x))`

full example :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def tempFuncAgg(tempVar):
    tempList = set(tempVar.dropna()) # Drop NaNs and create set of unique values
    print(tempList)
    return tempList

    # Define dataframe
    tempDF = pd.DataFrame({ 'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
                            'date': ["02/04/2015 02:34","06/04/2015 12:34","09/04/2015 23:03","12/04/2015 01:00","15/04/2015 07:12","21/04/2015 12:59","29/04/2015 17:33","04/05/2015 10:44","06/05/2015 11:12","10/05/2015 08:52","12/05/2015 14:19","19/05/2015 19:22","27/05/2015 22:31","01/06/2015 11:09","04/06/2015 12:57","10/06/2015 04:00","15/06/2015 03:23","19/06/2015 05:37","23/06/2015 13:41","27/06/2015 15:43"],
                            'gender': ["male","female","female","male","male","female","female",np.nan,"male","male","female","male","female","female","male","female","male","female",np.nan,"male"],
                            'age': ["young","old","old","old","old","old",np.nan,"old","old","young","young","old","young","young","old",np.nan,"old","young",np.nan,np.nan]})

# Groupby based on 2 categorical variables
tempGroupby = tempDF.groupby(['gender','age'])

# Aggregate for each variable in each group using function defined above
dfAgg = tempGroupby.agg(lambda x: tempFuncAgg(x))

# Transform in list
dfAgg.applymap(lambda x: list(x))

print(dfAgg)
```

There's many such bizzare behaviours in pandas, it is generally better to go on with a workaround (like this), than to find a perfect solution

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply and for confirming that I wasn't going totally mad. I suppose it's one of those gotchas that is learned through experience.